# setParameter for a numerical value in Java EE application JPQL query

Tags: java, java-ee-6, jpql

I'm developing an application with Java EE 6. I need to write a search function and this is what I came up with:

```
    books=getEntityManager().createQuery(
"SELECT b FROM BookEntity b WHERE b.ISBN LIKE ?1 OR b.title LIKE ?2 OR b.price = ?3 OR b.bookYear = ?4 OR b.bookLanguage LIKE ?5")
.setParameter(1, key)
.setParameter(2, key)
.setParameter(3, key)
.setParameter(4, key)
.setParameter(5, key)
.getResultList();
```

This causes exceptions and I found out that problem is that price and bookYear are float and integer values and this method works fine for string fields only. So I tried following:

```
    books=getEntityManager().createQuery(
"SELECT b FROM BookEntity b WHERE b.ISBN LIKE ?1 OR b.title LIKE ?2 OR b.price = ?3 OR b.bookYear = ?4 OR b.bookLanguage LIKE ?5")
.setParameter(1, key)
.setParameter(2, key)
.setParameter(3, Float.parseFloat(key))
.setParameter(4, Integer.parseInt(key))
.setParameter(5, key)
.getResultList();
```

It still doesn't work.
Please help me with this.

Honestly, I think they are the most unhelpful exceptions because they do not describe anything related to the problem. These are the exceptions I got each time I debugged the app, one per debug session.(I have listed them in the order I got them):

1.) "An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
 Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT b FROM APP.BOOKENTITY b WHERE ISBN LIKE ?1 OR TITLE LIKE ?2 OR PRICE LIKE ?3 OR BOOKYEAR LIKE ?4 OR BOOKLANGUAGE LIKE ?5], line 1, column 17: syntax error at [.].
 Internal Exception: UnwantedTokenException(found=., expected 80)"

2.) "An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
 Exception Description: Error compiling the query [SELECT b FROM BOOKENTITY b WHERE ISBN LIKE ?1 OR TITLE LIKE ?2 OR PRICE LIKE ?3 OR BOOKYEAR LIKE ?4 OR BOOKLANGUAGE LIKE ?5]. Unknown entity type [BOOKENTITY]."

3.) "An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
 Exception Description: Error compiling the query [SELECT b FROM BookEntity b WHERE ISBN LIKE ?1 OR title LIKE ?2 OR price LIKE ?3 OR bookYear LIKE ?4 OR bookLanguage LIKE ?5], line 1, column 33: unknown identification variable [isbn]. The FROM clause of the query does not declare an identification variable [isbn]."

4.) "An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
 Exception Description: Error compiling the query [SELECT b FROM BookEntity b WHERE b.isbn LIKE ?1 OR b.title LIKE ?2 OR b.price LIKE ?3 OR b.bookYear LIKE ?4 OR b.bookLanguage LIKE ?5], line 1, column 35: unknown state or association field [isbn] of class [ejb.BookEntity]."

5.) "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: No authorized routine named 'LIKE' of type 'FUNCTION' having compatible arguments was found."

Comment: Can you post the exceptions you received

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in reply.

Firstly the query which you have shown in code looks to be correct. I tried a similar example of parameterized LIKE and it works. But I am confused why did you use the 'key' variable for all the setParameters. Please check if the datatypes of the BOOKENTITY entity is taken care when you are setting the parameters using setParameter method.

All the first 4 exceptions are valid and it looks like you have corrected them and finally stuck up at the 5th exception if I am correct.

For the 5th exception kindly print few more details about the exception if any. Also please do check if the setParameters takes care of the datatypes of the BOOKENTITY for the 'key' variable.